# Rustdoc on gh-pages with Travis

Tags: github, rust, travis-ci

I have generated documentation [for my project](https://github.com/pengowen123/cmaes) with `cargo doc`, and it is made in the target/doc directory. I want to allow users to view this documentation without a local copy, but I cannot figure out how to push this documentation to the gh-pages branch of the repository. Travis CI would help me automatically do this, but I cannot get it to work either. I followed [this guide](https://github.com/steveklabnik/automatically_update_github_pages_with_travis_example), and set up a .travis.yml file and a deploy.sh script. According to the build logs, everything goes fine but the gh-pages branch never gets updated. My operating system is Windows 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is better to use [travis-cargo](https://github.com/huonw/travis-cargo), which is intended to simplify deploying docs and which also has other features. Its readme provides an example of `.travis.yml` file, although in the simplest form it could look like this:

```
language: rust
sudo: false

rust:
  - nightly
  - beta
  - stable

before_script:
  - pip install 'travis-cargo<0.2' --user && export PATH=$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH

script:
  - |
      travis-cargo build &&
      travis-cargo test &&
      travis-cargo --only beta doc

after_success:
  - travis-cargo --only beta doc-upload

# needed to forbid travis-cargo to pass `--feature nightly` when building with nightly compiler
env:
  global:
    - TRAVIS_CARGO_NIGHTLY_FEATURE=""
```

It is very self-descriptive, so it is obvious, for example, what to do if you want to use another Rust release train for building docs.

In order for the above `.travis.yml` to work, you need to set your `GH_TOKEN` somehow. There are basically two ways to do it: inside `.travis.yml` via an encrypted string, or by configuring it in the Travis itself, in project options. I prefer the latter way, so I don't need to install travis command line tool or pollute my `.travis.yml` (and so the above config file does not contain `secure` option), but you may choose otherwise.

Comment: I tried this and it builds and tests, but still does not push documentation to the gh-pages branch. A side note, following the tutorial for creating a gh-pages branch I accidentally deleted my project. I cloned it from Github, but I had to reinitialize the repository and now I can't push anything.

Comment: EDIT: I fixed the git issues but now I have to use `git push cmaes master` and `git pull cmaes master`, so it complicates things. I had to delete the repository on Github, and from now on I will keep a copy of my projects  somewhere else.

Comment: @pengowen123, this is all very strange. travis-cargo does not require absolutely anything for you to do with the repository. It should create gh-pages branch automatically. My workflow with all my projects using travis-cargo is absolutely no different from the workflow on other projects. Note that you do not need to keep gh-pages branch locally, unless you want to inspect the generated docs manually for some reason, so it is not mandatory to pull the repository after you push things there.

Comment: I deleted the gh-pages branch and it did not generate them when I pushed to the master branch. I have the target directory in my .gitignore as well, which might be a problem.

Comment: Nope, that shouldn't be a problem. What travis output do you have? If there are problems, it should be visible in the output.

Comment: I am using your .travis.yml, and travis says passing. I looked through the logs [here](https://travis-ci.org/pengowen123/cmaes), but there are no errors.

Comment: @pengowen123 but there [*are* errors](https://travis-ci.org/pengowen123/cmaes/jobs/108973629#L194). You should set your GH_TOKEN in order for travis-cargo to work, just as you'd do with the guide you are linking to. I usually do this in travis settings, but lots of examples on the net do this by embedding an encrypted string into `.travis.yml`. Do either way, and it should work.

Comment: I used the travis gem to encrypt my key, and now it works. I did not see any errors because I was looking on the stable branch, should have realized it would only error on beta from the travis-cargo command. Thanks for the help.